# Cropping an image in python (numpy), array reshape

Tags: python, numpy

I have an image of shape [h,w,3]. I want to make a square center crop of this image, that is an array of shape [min(h,w), min(h,w),3]. I'm using numpy. What I tried is this:

```
def image_center_crop(img):


cropped_img = np.reshape(img, (np.minimum(img.shape[0],img.shape[1]), np.minimum(img.shape[0],img.shape[1]),3))

return cropped_img
```

However, I'm getting an error ValueError: total size of new array must be unchanged. How can I reshape my array?

Comment: See if this helps - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39382412/crop-center-portion-of-a-numpy-image.

Comment: It works, thank you.